# swift 5-error: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."

Tags: php, swift, xcode, error-handling

i am new to swift programming and i am working on a login and registry xcode example i found online.
it said, it works with all sort of backends. so i changed it to work with my login.php file. but i come only so far ...

```
func handleResponse(for request: URLRequest,
                    completion: @escaping (Result<[User], Error>) -> Void) {

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            guard let unwrappedResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badResponse))
                return
            }

            print(unwrappedResponse.statusCode)

            switch unwrappedResponse.statusCode {

            case 200 ..< 300:
                print("success")

            default:
                print("failure")
            }

            if let unwrappedError = error {
                completion(.failure(unwrappedError))
                return
            }

            if let unwrappedData = data {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [])
                    print(json)
                    if let users = try? JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: unwrappedData) {
                        completion(.success(users))
                    } else {
                        let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                        completion(.failure(errorResponse))
                    }

                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

i have this request function.

```
func request(endpoint: String,
             loginObject: Login,
             completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

    guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + endpoint) else {
        completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    do {
        let loginData = try JSONEncoder().encode(loginObject)
        request.httpBody = loginData
        print(loginObject)
    } catch {
        completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badEncoding))
    }

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    handleResponse(for: request, completion: completion)
}
```

and then got this error

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

so i was searching online, mostly in here, what went wrong. i tested the code and found out where the error comes from and i found out, i should change my code to...

```
        if let unwrappedData = data {

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [])
                print(json)
                if let users = try? JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: unwrappedData) {
                    completion(.success(users))
                } else {
                    let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                    completion(.failure(errorResponse))
                }

            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
```

so i thought that is the proper fix for my problem. but unfortunately i got another error after this change...

```
Member 'success' in 'Result<User, Error>' produces result of type 'Result<Success, Failure>', but context expects 'Result<User, Error>'
```

and i cant even build and run the code anymore. can anybody help me?
if necessary i change my login.php from an array to dictionary.

is this the completion closure?

```
enum MyResult<T, E: Error> {

    case success(T)
    case failure(E) }



func handleResponse(for request: URLRequest,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {
        ... }


enum NetworkingError: Error {
    case badUrl
    case badResponse
    case badEncoding }
```

ErrorResponse.swift

```
import Foundation

struct ErrorResponse: Decodable, LocalizedError {
    let reason: String

    var errorDescription: String? { return reason } }
```

Login.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Login: Encodable {
    let username: String
    let password: String }
```

User.swift

```
import Foundation

struct User: Decodable {
    let user_id: Int
    let username: String
    let password: String
    let firstname: String
    let surname: String
    let activated: Int
    let reg_time: String
}
```

print(json) ...

```
({
        activated = 1;
        firstname = Thomas;
        password = Maggie;
        "reg_time" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
        surname = Ghost;
        "user_id" = 2;
        username = "testuser";
    })
```

now i am almost back in business. i found out that my user_id in mysql is int(3) but swift 5 doesnt take it as it should. when i take out let user_id: int, i finally get rid off the last error message. but now i can log in with any click of a button and any user and password, whether its right or wrong.

Comment: This error is because you are getting array in response but you are parsing it as dictionary. Can you please show the response you are getting.

Comment: Can you show us your json structure?

Comment: Yes, I found that out and changed it to ... if let users = try? JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: unwrappedData) {
                    completion(.success(users)) ... but then got a different error... as you see above!

Comment: Json structure: [ {"user_id":"2","username":"testuser","firstname":"Thomas","surname":"Ghost","password":"Maggie","reg_time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","activated":"1"}]

Comment: Can you provide ErrorResponse declaration as well?

Comment: import Foundation

struct ErrorResponse: Decodable, LocalizedError {
    let reason: String
    
    var errorDescription: String? { return reason }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in the signature of your completion closure.  Looks like you are using Swift.Result but varying the generic Success and Failure types.  Can you post the enclosing function where you are passing completion closure?

OK, try changing handleResponse to:

```
unc handleResponse(for request: URLRequest,
                    completion: @escaping (Result<[User], Error>) -> Void) {
    ... }
```

And ensure that ErrorResponse implements `Error`